# Failing to use a vector iterator, c++

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I'm trying to iterate over a vector holding a pointer to an object of type Student.
The declaration of vector is as follow: `static vector<Student*> students;`

Anyhow, I am trying to use an iterator in function pickWinners():

```
vector<Student*>::iterator p1 = students.begin();
vector<Student*>::iterator p2 = p1;
p2++;
```

As I understand, p1 is a pointer to a pointer to Student. But when I try this (for example):

```
*p1->print();
```

I get the next error:

> Hire.cpp:192: error: request for member ‘print’ in ‘* p1.__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::operator-> with _Iterator = Student**, _Container = std::vector >’, which is of non-class type ‘Student*’
>   make: *** [Hire.o] Error 1

This doesn't make any sense to me. I know the problem is not in print().
I tried

```
Student *student = students.at(0);
student->print();
```

and everything worked perfect. I'm pretty clueless here, any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The desired result would be achieved by

```
(*p1)->print();
```

In your case, the code parses as `*(p1->print());`, because `operator->` has higher precedence than `operator*`, see for example, [the precedence table on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++#Operator_precedence)

Answer (score 3):

You probably want/need `(*p1)->print();` As-is, it'll parse as if you'd written `*(p1->print());`

Chances are about 20:1 you'd really be better off storing `Student`s instead of `Student *`s.

Once you've fixed that, you probably want to get rid of `Student::print()` and instead  provide `std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &, Student const &);`. With that in place, you can do something like:

```
std::cout << *p1;
```

and (for example) printing your entire array works out to something like:

```
std::copy(students.begin(), students.end(), 
          std::ostream_iterator<Student>(std::cout, "\n"));
```

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Just calling the odds.

Answer (score 1):

p1 is an iterator and for the precedence rule the compiler is interpreting it like:

```
*(p1->print());
```

But what you want is:

```
(*p1)->print();
```