# Calling functions from an iterator

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, iterator, std

I'm getting an error in the `drawScreen()` function of my `Game` class.

```
void Game::drawScreen()
{
    window->clear();

    std::vector<sf::Drawable*>::iterator itr;

    for(int i = 0; i <= window->getSize().y; i++)
    {
        for(itr=drawableStack.begin(); itr!=drawableStack.end(); drawableStack.pop_back())
        {
            if(**itr.getPosition().y == i)
            {
                window->draw(**itr);
            }
        }
    }

    window->display();
}
```

The drawable stack is declared

```
std::vector<sf::Drawable*> drawableStack;
```

The error is at

```
if(**itr.getPosition().y == i)
```

It doesn't like the `**itr.getPosition()` and I'm not sure what to use in its place. Also, the goal of this function is to draw from the top of the screen down, so that things "farther away" are drawn first and objects closer to the foreground are drawn on top of them. If this doesn't seem like an efficient method of doing that let me know what would be better. I'm concerned that this may be slower when there's a bunch of objects being drawn.

Comment: What type does `getPosition` return?

Comment: How about  `(*itr)->getPosition()` ?

Comment: Operator precedence... `**itr.getPosition()` is parsed as `**(itr.getPosition())`.

Comment: It returns a Vector2i, which is why I get the y component of the vector which is an integer. That worked cnicutar thanks!

Comment: This question is no good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(**itr.getPosition().y == i)
```

Needs to be changed to

```
if((*itr)->getPosition().y == i) // preferred
```

Or

```
if((**itr).getPosition().y == i) // eh, ok
```

Comment: I had tried if(*itr->getPosition().y == i) before, didn't think to try wrapping it in parenthesis. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
if((*itr)->getPosition().y == i)
```

That may help...

With `*itr` you get the pointer, and with `(*itr)->` you use that pointer.

See also [Failing to use a vector iterator, c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7326599/failing-to-use-a-vector-iterator-c)